# Vertically Aligning Content in Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am building a website with Zurb Foundation. I want to include a DIV. This div will have two columns. The left column will show an image. The second column will hold a paragraph and a button. I want the button to be vertically aligned against the bottom of the grid. In other words, I want the bottom of my button to align with the bottom of my image. Currently, I am trying the following:

```
<div class="sample">
  <h1>This is the title</h1>
  <ul class="inline-list">
    <li>John Smith</li>
    <li>October 12, 2013</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-5 columns">
      <div>
        <img src="/images/paper.jpg" style="width:100%;" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="large-7 columns" style="background-color:yellow;">
      <p>A paragraph will go here</p>

      <a class="button small" href="[someUrl]">
        <span>keep reading</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="icon-arrow-right5" style="font-weight:lighter; vertical-align:middle;"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't get the "keep reading" button to vertically align with the bottom of the image in the left column. Is there a way to do this in Zurb Foundation? If so, how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to get this done is to float two containers (one for image and one for text) next to each other, with a paragraph text box and a button box inside of the text container.

Give the paragraph box a max-height that would approximate about 70-80% of your image's height (depending on how wide the paragraph box is) and put an overflow:hidden; on it in case your text runs long and you don't want your layout breaking. Place the button below the fixed height paragraph box with a simple top margin and you should be good.

You could align these boxes I've made with Zerb's grid to get this done, but Zerb's grid has horizontal columns only: you'll have to add in these vertical alignments to achieve your goal.

Check the code out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/73fct/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="http://nutritionwonderland.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/bee-emrank-flickr-300x300.png" width="300" height="300" alt="A Honey Bee" />
    </div>

    <div class="text-box">
        <p class="paragraph">
            Bees are an important part of the ecosystem that are increasingly being threatened by pesticides, fungi and a host of other pathogens. Bees are an important part of the ecosystem that are increasingly being threatened by pesticides, fungi and a host of other pathogens. Bees are an important part of the ecosystem that are increasingly being threatened by pesticides, fungi and a host of other pathogens.
        </p>
        <div class="button">Bees!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS (backgrounds on the elements are just to show structure for you):

```
.container {
    min-width: 480px;
}

.image-box {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.text-box {
    background: #ffa3d0;
    min-height: 300px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 180px;
}

.paragraph {
    background: #a3cdff;
    padding: 10px;
    max-height: 205px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
    background: #c5ffa3;
    margin: 5px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: I was playing with your fiddle. There's a problem. If the text does not take up the full height, the button is not aligned against the bottom edge of the image.

Comment: That's true, but you could put a min-height on .paragraph and get a similar result if you had a small paragraph.